# in as many minutes - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I have a problem with: Elizabeth nervously polished the glasses for the third time in as many minutes. How am I to understand the last part ... in as many minutes. in this sentence.

Help me please.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "as many" refers back to "third".

[As Many](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as-many):

> The same number of. For example, He changed jobs four times in as many years means he changed jobs four times in four years.

So in this case, "Elizabeth nervously polished the glasses for the third time in three minutes."